# Codeigniter MySQL filtering data as per user ID in the session

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have following function in my model to select records as per the user ID in the session.

```
public function getOfficer()
    {
     $usr = $this->session->userdata('id_user');
     $userArray = $this->db->order_by('last_name','ASC')->where_in('tbl_officer.p_code', [8,10,24]);
     $userArray1 = $this->db->order_by('last_name','ASC')->get_where('tbl_officer', array('status' => 1, 'usr'=>$this->session->userdata('id_user')));

     if($usr == 4){
        $this->db->where('p_code',$userArray );
     }else{
        $this->db->where('usr',$userArray1);
     }
     $q = $this->db->get('tbl_officer');
     if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $q->result();
     }
     return false;
    }
```

If the user 4 in the session, records should be filtered by p_code [8,10,24] and any other user in the session, records should be filtered as per usr. usr column includes user ids like 1,2,3,4 etc.

But the function outs following error and didn't get the expected result.

> Error Number: 42000/1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE `p_code` =' at line 2
>
> SELECT * WHERE `p_code` =
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/doahrm/application/models/Officer_model.php
>
> Line Number: 106

Line Number 106 is `$q = $this->db->get();` in the function.

What may be going wrong ? Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the raw sql, the `from table_name` is lost:

```sql
SELECT * WHERE `p_code` = ...
```

So you are lossing your table:

```php
$q = $this->db->get('table_name');
```

And I think your code need to look like this:

```php
public function getOfficer()
{
     $usr = $this->session->userdata('id_user');
     if ($usr == 4) {
         $query = $this->db->order_by('last_name','ASC')->where_in('tbl_officer.p_code', [8,10,24]);
     } else {
         $query = $this->db->order_by('last_name','ASC')
                           ->where(array('status' => 1, 'usr'=>$usr));
     }
     $query = $query->get('tbl_officer');
     if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
         return $query->result();
     } else {
         return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: @ TsaiKoga. Modified as my edit. But still with the same issue.

Comment: @ TsaiKoga. That is Error Number: 42000/1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

SELECT * FROM `tbl_officer` WHERE `p_code` =

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/doahrm/application/models/Officer_model.php

Line Number: 107

Comment: @ TsaiKoga. SELECT * FROM `tbl_officer` WHERE `p_code` =

Comment: @MCITTrends Now it can find your table. But new error occurs on Officer_model.php Line Number: 107, what is the code on this line?

Comment: @ TsaiKoga. $q = $this->db->get('tbl_officer');

Comment: @MCITTrends It seems the `$userArray` is return Filename. what do u really want for this variable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206646/discussion-between-mcit-trends-and-tsaikoga).